# Not able to push next view after clicking a uibutton which is on the top right of the view

Tags: iphone

i am having a view consisting of a tableview and a uibutton like this[image]

when i click on button "add" a new class/xib named "Locsetting" should be open.which i am not able to do.
my code: .h file

```
    @interface LocationViewController : UIViewController     <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>    
 {  
    UITableView *table;    
    NSMutableArray *menuList;  
    LocSetting *locSetting;  
    IBOutlet UIButton *addbutton;  
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *menuList;  
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITableView *table;  
@property (nonatomic,retain) LocSetting *locSetting;  
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *addbutton;  
-(IBAction)gotoLocSetting:(id) sender;  
@end

  My .m :    

@synthesize addbutton;  
-(IBAction)gotoLocSetting:(id) sender    {
    NSLog(@"gotoLocSetting Entered");  
    locSetting = [[LocSetting alloc]
                  initWithNibName:@"LocSetting"
                  bundle:nil];  
    //locationViewController.menuList = [menuList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:locSetting
                                         animated:YES];  
    [locSetting release];  

}
```

what wrong i am doing?or please guide me!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the IBAction is connected properly to the button. And I think its better to have `IBOutlet UIButton *addbutton;`  alone and `@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *addbutton;`

Comment: thanks!IbAction was not connected.Problem solved.BUT what you are talkin about"And I think its better to have IBOutlet UIButton *addbutton; alone and @property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *addbutton;" .sorry i cant understand.

Comment: I meant u just need to make any one of them as IBOutlet rather than both

Answer (score 1):

On a quick look, there might be one of the following 3 problems:

1. Is your IBAction linked to the button's outlet?
2. If not, try removing `LocSetting *locSetting;` and its property/synthesize. Next, change your line down there to: `Locsetting *locSetting = [[LocSetting alloc] initWithNibName:@"LocSetting" bundle:nil];`
3. If that doesn't work, try changing that to: `Locsetting *locSetting = [[LocSetting alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];`

Comment: Thank you very much !i solve the problem however i am next going to play with the tricks given by you in option 2. and 3.

Comment: @Maddy yeah, play around a bit with the nibnames, there is quite a logic behind it. Good thing you found the error! ^^